# Tableau CRM Dataflow: sfdcDigest or sfdcFilter to only return record with latest value on a date field

Tags: einstein-analytics, dataflow, tableau-crm

I am creating a TCRM dataflow and would like a sfdcDigest to return the record with the latest value in a date field (or to achieve this using a subsequent sfdcFilter).

More details on this use case:
For each Parent, there can be multiple Child records. If there are multiple child records that meet the basic set of criteria criteria, then I only want to return the child record with the latest CreatedDate.

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was a Compute Relative node :)